# how to use git diff show some invisible characters differences?

Tags: git

When I use `git diff`, I saw the differences like below:

```
-    self.conv_2 = nn.Conv2d(C_in, C_out // 2, 1, stride=2, padding=0, bias=False) 
+    self.conv_2 = nn.Conv2d(C_in, C_out // 2, 1, stride=2, padding=0, bias=False)
```

And I'm sure there are no white backspace difference in these two lines.
However, I think these two lines are totally same.

I wonder why does git think they are different?

And is there a way to let `git diff` show the special characters difference?

Comment: Check line endings. Check whitespaces in general. If still there are no differences, check invisible characters.

Comment: Those two lines might differ in their line-endings. Take a look [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings)

Comment: @dyukha  thanks for comments. I'm sure they don't have white backspace in the endings. So how to check invisible characters?

Comment: Whitespace can be not only in the ending; for example, it can be <tab> vs spaces in the beginning. I'm not sure how what's the simple way to check for invisible characters. First, you may try some other diff viewers. By yourself you may write the program which reads strings from file and prints them, char by char, with some separator.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [`--ws-error-highlight` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---ws-error-highlightltkindgt) might be useful.

```
git diff --ws-error-highlight=all
```

Alternatively, you can pipe the `git diff` output to `cat` and use its `-A` flag to explicitly print a variety of non-printing characters.

```
git diff | cat -A
```

Comment: The first option doesn't highlight differences like spaces changed to tabs. The second works great.

Comment: The second option was very helpful.  Thank you :)