# Pull request in git showing full diff for few files even though it has changes in few lines

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-pull

[image]Pull request in git showing full diff for few files even though it has changes in few lines. Dont know how to fix this problem. If there is any git command which will fix this pls let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git-diff to ignore ^M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889559/git-diff-to-ignore-m)

Comment: This is related to changing of newlines windows (\r\n) vs Linux (\n), you can find enough existing questions about this.

Comment: My pull request is not having ^M. Also tried to save file to unix like :e ++ff=dos  then :set ff=unix & :wq. It also didn't helped.

Comment: Did you replace tabs by spaces or vice/versa?

Comment: No i did not replaced tabs or vice versa

Comment: Can you then clarify what you see? Maybe with a screenshot or output of the command line? A pull request is not directly in git, what software are you using for that?

Comment: I am using eclipse to push the changes to remote repository & from github raised pull request.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58037244/6330106.

Answer (score 2):

There is a **Diff setting** button in the pull request. Click on it then apply **Hide whitespace changes**. Solved the problem.

Comment: What whitespace other than tabs/spaces or newlines do you think this ignored for you?

Comment: I am not seeing the same line has removed and added anywhere in pull request.